# Laravel 4 and Iron.io multiple queue / PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue, iron.io

I started to take a look Iron.io as service for my queue process. With the easy set up in laravel I make it work in a couple of minutes but there is something that is not clear to me.

I subscribed a new queue called `resizer` using the artisan command as the following:

```
php artisan queue:subscribe resizer http://mywebsite.com/queue/resizer
```

On the settings in the `queue.php` file I have to give the name on the key `queue` of the queue created in this case `resizer`

```
'iron' => array(
            'driver'  => 'iron',
            'host'    => 'mq-aws-us-east-1.iron.io',
            'token'   => 'xxxxxx',
            'project' => 'xxxx',
            'queue'   => 'resizer',
            'encrypt' => true,
        ),
```

But for sure I will have others kind of queues. This resizer queue is responsible to resize images, but I will have to set up another one for send `email` maybe called `email`.

Now let's say that I want implement the `email` queue and also have the `resizer` well i thought just subscribe another service.

```
 php artisan queue:subscribe email http://mywebsite.com/queue/email
```

my routes:

```
Route::post('queue/resizer', function()
{
    Queue::marshal();
});

Route::post('queue/email', function()
{
    Queue::marshal();
});
```

**Problem:**

When I Hit the route `queue/email` Iron.io fire the `resizer` instead the `email` process adding 1 more message to that queue because on the settings I set up `resizer`. 
So how can I have different tasks / queue to assign to Iron.io each one for differents needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pushRaw function

`pushRaw($payload, $queue = null, array $options = array())`

Example:

`Queue::pushRaw("This is Hello World payload", "email");`

Comment: Thanks for you kind answer, can you be a bit more specific please. I never used this method, it need to be used on the route instead `Queue::marshal()`? what does this method?

Comment: The `marshal` method will take care of firing the correct job handler class. To fire jobs onto the push queue, just use the same `Queue::push` method used for conventional queues or `Queue::pushRaw` to push messages to specific queue.